# How to insert different values ​in a search field with the same button?

Tags: javascript, html

The values ​​cannot be the same, for example, when you click the button the first time, the word "Decoration" appears, when you click it again, for example "Health", then "Fun," then "Yesterday 4", up to a maximum of 9 words and then back to the first one (Decoration). Do not forget that the previous value must be replaced by the new value.

You can see this example but it just inserts 1 value, so maybe it can be changed to the desired effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/62wLqz37/

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="set_Value" id="set_Value" value="submit" onclick="setValue()" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    function setValue() {
    
        document.getElementById('bbb').value = "Decoração";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to set value randomly ?

Comment: Thank you, but I preferred it in order. However, I can study both examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do randomly.

```js
const myValues = ['Decoration', 'Health', 'Fun', 'Yesterday 4'];

function setValue() {
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * myValues.length); ;
    document.getElementById('bbb').value = myValues[randomNum];
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <p>
    <input type="button" name="set_Value" id="set_Value" value="submit" onclick="setValue()" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
    </label>
  </p>
</form>
```

And this is how you do by order increment

```js
const myValues = ['Decoration', 'Health', 'Fun', 'Yesterday 4'];
let myInd = 0;

function setValue() {
    document.getElementById('bbb').value = myValues[myInd];
    myInd = myInd >= (myValues.length - 1) ? 0 : myInd+1;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <p>
    <input type="button" name="set_Value" id="set_Value" value="submit" onclick="setValue()" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
    </label>
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```js
var valueArrs = ["tidy", "fun", "party", "pool", "sun", "moon", "human", "cat", "apple"];
//some nonsense
var a = 0;
function setValue(valueArrs) {
  if (a<=7) {
    document.getElementById("bbb").value = valueArrs[a];
    a++;
   }
   else {
    document.getElementById("bbb").value = valueArrs[a];
    a=0;
   }
 }
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <p><input type="button" name="set_Value" id="set_Value" value="submit" onclick="setValue(valueArrs)" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect.